# MongoDB - 3 types of roles

Tags: database, mongodb

I have a user model here that currently only have 2 possible roles. One is admin and one is regular user.

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    isAdmin: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,
        default: false
    }
}, { timestamps: true
})
```

As you can see, if the `isAdmin` was set to true, it will automatically become an admin otherwise its a regular user.

But things change when I added a new role like: `isOwner` which is I added a new field again:

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    isAdmin: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,
        default: false
    },
isOwner: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,
        default: false
    },, { timestamps: true
})
```

As you can see I added a new field `isOwner` at the top.

My question is given these three roles: `isAdmin`, `isOwner` and regular user, am I doing the right way to do this and manage 3 different roles? or is there a better way to do this?

**Note**: The way this works is that admin has the overall access to all of the job post of the owner while the regular user can only comment on the job post posted by the owner (who posted the job)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In future you may have more roles, It is best to use Array field for user roles.

[array reference document](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays)

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    isAdmin: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,
        default: false
    },
    roles: {
        type:[String],
        required: true,
        default:["regular"]
    }
    },
 { timestamps: true
})
```

Comment: How does this work? Can you site an example based on my needs please? I am complete beginner

Comment: const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    isAdmin: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,
        default: false
    },
    roles: {
        type:[String],
        required: true,
        default:["regular"]
    }
    },
 { timestamps: true
})

Comment: Can you show me how to set this then when adding new records?